# Django - Update certain fields of a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

Model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
  tutor = models.ForeignKey(User)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
  status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Form:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Session
    exclude = ['tutor']
```

Testing:

```
>>> ses = Session.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> ses
<Session: Robert - 2012-04-18 13:00:00>
>>> form = SessionForm(instance=ses)
```

Now for example, I'd like to update only the `status` of this instance and save it.
How can I do that ?

---

**edit**

Template:

```
<form action="fhjsdhkl" method="POST">{{ csrf_token }}
  <input name="start_time" />
  <input name="end_time" />
</form>
```

Trying to post only these 2 fields:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = SessionForm(request.POST)
  if request.POST['id']:
    try:
      s = Session.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
      form.instance = s
    except Session.DoesNotExist:
      pass
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

> The Session could not be changed because the data didn't validate.

The error return by the form is

> status - This field is required

The fields that I need to update are not fixed, and I'd like to avoid posting all the fields each time. Do I have to make a different form for each case ?

Comment: Why do you need the form at all?

Comment: I'm giving an example with only one field but I'm actually doing multiple fields from a template <form />

Comment: What validation error do you get?

Comment: Are you certain that start_time and end_time have the correct format? It should be in the same format: 2012-04-18 13:00:00 If it is different, like say, MM-DD-YYYY TIME you will raise validation errors as well. If status is present in the database, when you create a model from that row, it will also be present. So, when you do form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance=ses) you will not raise validation errors because of it. Indeed, if status was missing you should be getting a "this is a required field" error. This is a data validation error.

Comment: "status - this field is required" is the error. Please see the edit

Comment: In your above edited question, you are still do not have "request.POST" as the first argument, but below you said that is what you are doing. I feel like there is something missing here.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Did you originally save this data to the database by using something other than django? Also, have you verified that in that particular row you are querying, that status is not null?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY You should post your view. I feel like there is something missing

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY your problem is in your view. I'll update my answer with an explanation

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113616/django-hidden-foreign-key-in-form-using-meta-model/10113731#10113731) shows how you can exclude a required field from a model form (as you want to exclude `status`) then manually set it after the form is submitted.

Comment: I'm going to vote for deleting this post because I have not been able to make my question clear. I have done a new one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223891

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 2: The old answer is irrelevant

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = SessionForm(request.POST)
  if request.POST['id']:
    try:
      s = Session.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
      form.instance = s
    except Session.DoesNotExist:
      pass
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Ok, you have a number of things going on here:

1.

This line should be like this:

```
form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance = s)
```

2.

You should move the session object up:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    s = get_object_or_404(Session, pk=request.POST['id'])
    form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance = s)
```

If you do the try and except method below, you will raise validation errors whenever that object doesn't exist. Throw a 404 instead. Docs are here on the above shortcut: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404 You will need to import it if you haven't already.

Now you can valuidate it and save it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    s = get_object_or_404(Session, pk=request.POST['id'])
    form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance = s)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

3.

Furthermore, you should not do this: if request.POST['id'] as strings are never False, even empty strings. For example, try this in IDLE:

```
>>> '' == True
>>> '' == False

>>> 'a' == True
>>> 'a' == False
```

You will note this always evaluates to False.

So, what you view was never actually creating the reference model.

Comment: I'm giving an example on only one field but I'm actually doing multiple sent from a template <form /> (I didn't -1)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY  I had a slight error, which I corrected. It's probably why I got neged. Anyway, I made some edits.

Comment: I have also changed my comment :)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY typically you would just use the POST data as an argument to the modelform, which will take care of validation as well. You may want to edit your question to include this. Doing something like this:  form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance=ses) would be typical.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but as I don't post all the fields, the form doesn't get validated, I'm going to update my question.