# Django - ModelForm Dynamic field update

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to update certain fields a ModelForm, these fields are not fixed. (I have only `tutor` that is autopopulated by the view)

Model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
  tutor = models.ForeignKey(User)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
  status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Form:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Session
    exclude = ['tutor']
```

For a given session sometimes I need to update only `end_time`, sometimes only `start_time` & `end_time`.

How can I do that in a view ?

---

**Edit**

I have given examples but it's not limited to these examples, the fields I need to update are not predefined, I need to be able to update any field(s)

Comment: When you say 'update', what do you mean? Do you render all form fields or just those to be updated?

Comment: I render only those updated. (update I mean change the value)

Comment: Could you take an example for this, like usage scene? Still not very sure your purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had to do something similar before, and while it isn't exactly pretty, it is quite effective. It involves dynamically creating a type at runtime, and using that type. For some documentation, you can see [DynamicModels for django.](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)

Here we go.. your requirements.

- You want to be able to update a model using a form
- You want to selectively specify which fields are to be updated at run-time

So, some code:

```
def create_form(model, field_names):
    # the inner class is the only useful bit of your ModelForm
    class Meta:
        pass
    setattr(Meta, 'model', model)
    setattr(Meta, 'include', field_names)
    attrs = {'Meta': Meta}

    name = 'DynamicForm'
    baseclasses = (forms.ModelForm,)
    form = type('DynamicForm', baseclasses, attrs)
    return form

def my_awesome_view(request):
    fields = ['start_time', 'end_time']
    form = create_form(Session, fields)
    # work with your form!
```

Comment: I like this one. What is not pretty ?

Comment: I should say, it's not intuitive. I wrote the 'not pretty' comment when thinking about my implementation for dynamic tables. This actually looks fairly elegant.

Comment: Why not directly generate and return the form? constructing by `type()` is useful for dynamic model which has dynamic fields in `attrs`, in your code `attrs` only has the `Meta` class. Anyway.

Comment: @okm, I intentionally made the example longer than it needed to be to demonstrate the different parts to the answer. I'd still use a function to create the dynamic class though, as declaring a Meta type in a view would look suspect.

Comment: if I have to override some property of the fields i would do it in `__init__` method. Here How can we write `__init__` method dynamically?

Comment: @Navaneethan I haven't tried, and I'm not sure, but you could try creating a regular ModelForm with your init method, and then using that in the `baseclasses` tuple, rather than the ModelForm.

Answer (score 1):

Put your form fields as nullable and with "clean" methods you can add logic to fields ex:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_end_date(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if (cd["start_date"] and cd["end_date"]) and cd["end_date"] < cd["start_date"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("WTF?!")
        if not (cd["start_date"] or cd["end_date"]):
            raise forms.ValidationError("need one date")
        return cd['end_date']
```

If you want to change value, use a different value to the return statement.

This is what you may need for validation.

If you want, you may copy GET dictionary in your view and update values before instanciate your form

```
def my_view(request):
    r_data = request.GET.copy()
    r_data.merge(request.POST)

    data = dict([(key, my_function(key, value)) for key, value in r_data.iteritems() if key in MyForm.fields])
    form = MyForm(data=data)
    [...]
```

hopes it help.

Comment: Not exactly responding to my question but your validation rules are interesting, I'll use them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke form's constructor like this:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Session
        exclude = ['tutor', 'start_time']

    def __init__(self, your_extra_args, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if need_end_time_start_time(your_extra_args):
            self.fields['start_time'] = forms.DateTimeField()
```

To use this class, you have to pass an argument "your_extra_args" to your form:

```
session_form = SessionForm('foo')
```

Comment: If I have a model with 10 fields and each one is updatable independently, you mean I have to do that for each ?

Comment: In that case, you should have the rule for which one has to be updated right? Give your 10 fields' name a convention like field_1, field_2, ... and then you should use a loop to do that in one step.

Comment: or use kwargs, you'll be able with setattr to translate values easily. but I think, copy your post/get query dict and modify it in the view may be a good way for you, you'll be able to eterate on fields and compute what you want then validate your modification through the form.

Comment: @christophe31, I don't think so, using constructor will save you from redundant fields and make your html smaller, faster in validating ...It's a good way to keep your logic flow and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you have a requirement that uses same model but different fields are hidden in your ModelForm, based on your needs.

If I understand your question, then you need to Create two different ModelForm based class, both these classes have same model value inside the Meta class. Exclude and include the fields you need. So now you have different ModelForm classes which you can call inside your view logic.

With this you will have two different forms that depend on same model, with different default fields.

With clever url and view design you will be able to use the above idea to serve multiple forms from same model.