# is there any method available in django models, so that i can access its fieldname using string?

Tags: python, ajax, django

i want to update fields using ajax:

### models.py

```
class EmployerInfo(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer, unique=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

### contactinfo.html

```
<form id="ajax-form">
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Contact Information</legend> 
        <label>Address:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="address" value="{{ empinfo.address }}" />
        <label>City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" value="{{ empinfo.city }}" /> <i class="icon-ok"></i>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("form#ajax-form").find(":input").change(function()
     {
       var field_name=$(this).attr("id");
       var field_val=$(this).val();
       var params ={ param1:field_name, param2:field_val };

       $.ajax({ url: "/employer/contactinfo/save/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: params,           
                success: setResult      
             });
    });
});
```

### urls.py

.....other urls

```
url(r'^employer/contactinfo/save/$', 'save_employer_info_ajax'),
```

### view.py

```
def save_employer_info_ajax(request):
    emp=Employer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    emp_info=EmployerInfo.objects.get(employer=emp)
    f_name=request.GET['param1']
    f_value=request.GET['param2']
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"issuccess": 'yes'}), content_type="application/json")
```

f_name the name of the field i want to update. lets assume it be 'address'.
how can i access that attribute, (ie emp_info.address) so that i can update (ie emp_info.address=f_value) using emp_info.save() function.

**is there any method available other than emp_info.address, so that i can access the field name using string (ie emp_info[f_name]=f_value ) or something??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use getattr baked into python

```
attr_name = 'employer_id'

if getattr(employee, attr_name) == 3:
    ...
```

Comment: it works. i guessed and used setattr()(ie setattr(emp_info, f_name) == f_value) to set the value and it works too.. thanks

Comment: And in turn setattr if you want to edit the in-memory model instances rather than using update to directly update the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [update method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) on the queryset object. It's a bit hacky since you are really only wanting to update a single object though.

```
def save_employer_info_ajax(request):
    emp_info_query = EmployerInfo.objects.filter(employer__user=request.user)
    update_dict = {request.GET['param1'] : request.GET['param2'] }
    emp_info_query.update(**update_dict)
```

Notice that I'm using reverse lookup relations to access `EmployerInfo` based on the `user` field of the `Employer` model. Then you construct a dictionary to hold the keys and values you wish to update, and pass that to the update method of the **queryset**, not the **model instance**.

You **should** be using forms for data entry though. There should be validation on all fields that you're entering into your database. You can use [dynamic forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223891/django-modelform-dynamic-field-update/10230117#10230117) to specify the fields you want included based on the values that you submit via ajax.

Comment: i only needed to update a single field so i am using setattr()(ie setattr(emp_info, f_name) == f_value) to set the value